# Using a boolean expression in a __str__ method in python

Tags: python, boolean, tostring

I have an issue regarding my program in my **str** method in python.

So in my tostring method I am printing out the information of a user. The issue i am having is when i print the data, for if the user wants to be on the mailing list.

That piece i want to put as a boolean answer, so "yes" or "no".

I am trying to figure out how to use a temp variable so that for my first customer it shows "yes" and the second one it shows "no"

```
class person(Person):
    def __init__(self):
        super().init(name,address,phone)

    def __str__(self):
        return super().__str__()

class Customer(Person):
    def __init__(self,name,address,phone,Num,Mail):
        super().__init__(name,address,phone)
        self._cusNum = Num
        self._mailList = Mail

    @property
    def Num(self):
        return self._cusNum

    @property
    def Mail(Self):
        return self._mailList

    @Num.setter
    def Num(self,Number):
        self._cusNum = Number

    @Mail.setter
    def Mail(self,List):
        self._mailList = List
```

Below is the issue:

```
    def __str__(self):
        return super().__str__() + " Customer Num: " + str(self._cusNum) + " Mailing List? "
        if self._mailList == temp:
            _mailList = "Yes"
        else:
            _mailList = "No"
        return _mailList
```

This is where the issue is, I want to use the "_mailList" variable to make it to a boolean expression.

```
from Person import*
def main():
    person1 = Customer("John Smith", "5 myStreet","973-111-1111",1,True)
    person2 = Customer("Henry Haus", "1 myHouse","973-222-2222",2,False)
    print(person1)
    print(person2)

main()
```

This above is the class that calls the objects and the last variable being true and false

This is what I was told to do below
" Boolean data attribute which indicates
whether the customer wants to be in the mailing list or not. "

Comment: You have a `return` as the first statement in your `__str__` so it will exit at that point without executing the `if`.

Comment: Did you mean `temp = super().__str__() + ...`?

Comment: What is `self._mailList`? Why are you writing `print(person)` when you only defined `person1` and `person2`?

Comment: @chepner its been updated i was doing adjustments to it

Comment: @Prune i added the class, if i was to add all of it, it would be useless, when the error is only in the toString method

Comment: @chepner is a variable that is being used as a boolean expression to see if the customer wants to be on the mailing list or not, like i said above "yes" or "no"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is convert the boolean value `self._mailList` to a string, then *add* that to the rest.

```
def __str__(self):
    return "{} Customer Num: {} Mailing List? {}".format(
        super().__str__(),
        self._cusNum,
        "Yes" if self._mailList else "No"
    )
```